# Output a list to a file

Tags: java, compiler-errors, java-io

I have a list that I want to output to a file. Each element in the list should be saved in a new line in the file. I'm able to print the list but when I output it to a file, it's empty.

`UIFileChooser` is from this library https://ecs.wgtn.ac.nz/foswiki/pub/Main/JavaResources/UIFileChooser.html

```
public List <String> myList = new ArrayList<String>();

    public void saveToFile(List<String> myList) {
        String filename = UIFileChooser.save("Filename to save to");
        try {
            PrintStream outfile = new PrintStream(filename);
            for (String line: myList) {
                outfile.println(line);
            }
            outfile.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {UI.println("File failure: " + e);}
    }
```

Comment: This might help you: https://mkyong.com/java/java-how-to-create-and-write-to-a-file/

Comment: Are you aware that `PrintStream` swallows exceptions? Try it with a `BufferedWriter` and see what the exception was.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find the solution below. Tested and it works.

```java
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintStream;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

class Main {

    public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException {

        List<String> myList = new ArrayList<String>();
        myList.add("a");
        myList.add("b");
        myList.add("c");
        myList.add("d");
        saveToFile(myList);

    }

    public static void saveToFile(List<String> myList) throws IOException {
        File output = new File("file.txt");
        output.createNewFile();

        PrintStream write = new PrintStream(output);
        for (String line : myList) {
            write.println(line);
        }
        write.close();

    }

}
```

`file.txt` output:

> a 
> b
> c
> d

Change this part:

```java
File output = new File("file.txt");
output.createNewFile();
PrintStream write = new PrintStream(output);
```

with this line of code if you want to append to already existing file:

```java
PrintStream write = new PrintStream(new FileOutputStream("file.txt", true));
```

Comment: thank you it works.  Do you know why my code didn't work ?

Comment: So, you don't get any error but file is empty. Could you make sure that your ```List``` is not empty? And could you test if ```UIFileChooser.save()``` returns the expected ```String```?

Comment: I downloaded ```UIFileChooser```, tested your code and it worked. Are you sure that you tried to call it with non-empty ```List```?

Comment: yeah I'm sure the list is not empty. I printed it out in the same class

Comment: `output.createNewFile()` was never necessary in the first place.